# Border radius in percentage

Tags: html, css, percentage

In CSS it is allowed to write something like this.

```
#div-with-border {
  width: 100%;   // scales with parent wrapper
  height: 30%;   // scales with parent wrapper

  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
```

If `#div-width-border` isn't a perfect square the border won't be a circle, since this means, that 10% of the width and 10% of the height are used for the border-radius (which differ). I would like to get perfect circles... I can't use `px`, since the border-radius depends on the height/width.

I'm sure that the width of `#div-width-border` is always greater than the height, of the element. I would need a border radius of the size `100% of element height` to get a perfect circle, but just `100%` won't do it, since it'll use the element width for one part of the radius calculation.

Comment: Did you try `50%`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm in a different situation here, since the div isn't a perfect square and I need percentages to make the border a circle independent of the divs width/height.

Comment: That is not the question you've written; please [edit].

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's exactly, what I've written. "*I can't use `px`...*", "*If `#div-width-border` isn't a perfect square...*", etc.

Comment: It's not. You mention 10% and 100%, neither of which make any sense; most of your question is basically red herrings Try *"How can you crop a non-square div into a circle? I know you can use `border-radius: 50%;` if the div is a square, but mine is not. Also it varies with the size of its parent so I can't use an absolute px size."*

Comment: Well see you doesn't want to achieve perfect circle using height and width of same i.e. in square and then border-radius of 50%, but you could add padding into it and then add border-radius of 50%.

Comment: Oh and maybe throw in a stack snippet of your closest attempt, a [mcve] is often helpful.

Comment: Are you asking how to make each corner a perfect quarter-circle?

Comment: If you get answer for your question,don't forget to post codes.

Answer (score 5):

If you know the ratio between the width and the height, you may use the Slash-Annotation to specify different %-values for horizontal and vertical border-radius. An Example is below:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.div-with-border {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10% / 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div-with-border"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are a life saver. I had no idea slash-annotation was a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `border-radius: 50%;` ? Since you're saying that the div is a perfect square, setting border radius to 50% should work

Comment: Sorry, of course I meant if the div *isn't* a perfect square. Edit..

Comment: The info inside the div will get cropped since you want it to be circular. The div should be square in shape to convert it into a perfect circle. You should consider adding padding to avoid cropping or overflow of the contents of the div. Is it okay if your div has an overflow property? Otherwise the div will be oval in shape as the width is larger than the height.

Comment: @hulking I mean, that the border forms a perfect circle. Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pzxb170m/1/): of course the div isn't.

Comment: Yeah, thats ok, what i am saying is that, you need to have padding inside the div to reduce the width of the content so that the width matches the dimensions of the height to create a circular div.